# W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@5680b5b

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I Got error

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@bbad44f
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@bbad44f
```

Here is my Gradle file

[App Gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OWy.png)
[Project Gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3crYF.png)

I tried all method but none of them work for me.

*****Edited*****

As Alex suggested removing [implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2']
solve the issue but i want to push some data to firebase here is my code im using DB refrence

```
mRootref = new Firebase("https://mpay-infoters.firebaseio.com/users");
    Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String FName_str = FName.getText().toString();
            String LName_str = LName.getText().toString();
            String Email_str = Email.getText().toString();
            String DocInput_str = DocInput.getText().toString();
            DatabaseReference mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
            DatabaseReference currentdb = mdatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            currentdb.child("Phone No").setValue(PhoneNumber);
            currentdb.child("First Name").setValue(FName_str);
            currentdb.child("Last Name").setValue(LName_str);
            currentdb.child("Email").setValue(Email_str);
            currentdb.child(DocTitle).setValue(DocInput_str);
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterUserDetailsActivity.this,Bottom_nav.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

Along with the other dependencies, which I see, all are the latest versions. To solve this, just remove the implementation above.

You can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more informations.

Beside that, please be also sure to have the latest version of Google Services.

Comment: Hi rishikesh_07! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it work.thank you!  But I'm using this [implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'] to push some data to firebase is their any other method to pushing data to firebase.

Comment: @rishikesh_07 You're welcome and good to hear that it worked!