# Weird warning when using Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using the latest versions of Firebase dependecies:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0
```

And:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

The authentication works fine but I continuously get:

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@9bbf57c

Everytime I create an account or I log-in. I've searched all answers here on SOF but with no luck :( How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Chech **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148875/w-bichannelgoogleapi-firebaseauth-getgoogleapiformethod-returned-gms-com)** out.

Comment: @AlexMamo Those are old versions.